# scroll down to loading more content

Tags: jquery, scroll, loading

I have a html page which is very long with li tag content. I dont want load them at once. I want it loading more about 10 li tag when the user scroll down to read. The page will per loading 15 li tag. And the page total may be 100 li tag. Is there any javascript can handle it?

for example

- 
- 

after user scroll down

- 
- 
- 
- 

Comment: Google `lazyload content`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment but I would suggest to try some code first. Also you can do it like this i won't do all code you should do it but I can lead you.
This example is similar to get alert after scroll and I can tell you you can get position of some div with jquery what will you need after new load to see where should new loading start.

```
   $(function(){
        $(window).bind("scroll.alert", function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.scrollTop() >= 100) {
                alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
                $this.unbind("scroll.alert");
            }
        });
    });
```

UPDATE:

It depends what you want. You can do it for each 100px scroll down do something or to get position
[Jquery position of some element](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

and update your code okay i god div position after i scroll there I want to apear new content and get new position.

But if you want to do it with php and database it would be easier.
This way you need to set other links as display: none; and after scroll change their css or just animate them there.